# dbt CLI string variables get inserted as integers from YAML dictionary

Tags: dbt

I'm trying to run the `run` command with some custom values:

```
dbt run --vars "{start_date: '2022-08-01', end_date: '2022-08-02'}"
```

and then use these variables in contexts like:

```
WHERE session_date BETWEEN {{ var('start_date') }} AND {{ var('end_date') }}
```

The values need to be inserted as strings (with single quotes kept), but it gets compiled as:

```
WHERE session_date BETWEEN 2022-08-01 AND 2022-08-02
```

which then is incorrect SQL ("No matching signature for operator BETWEEN for argument types: DATE, INT64, INT64"). I have tried switching the single and double quotes, but the problem remains.

How can I make it respect the quotes passed in the YAML dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by simply adding single quotes around the variable statements:

```
WHERE session_date BETWEEN '{{ var("start_date") }}' AND '{{ var("end_date") }}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the postgresql [TO_DATE](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/to_date.php) function to convert your input `string` variable to a `datetime` variable for easier comparison.

E.g)

```
WHERE session_date BETWEEN to_date({{ var('start_date') }}) AND to_date({{ var('end_date') }})
```

Comment: The problem is that it gets inserted as a non-string in the SQL code, so any function like that will fail.

Comment: Oh. So using escape characters didn't help with that either?